# Database with GUI on SharePoint

Tags: database, user-interface, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need a rescue! I have database in MS Access which contains list of computers in company(number, RAM, CPU, department, location, name, surname etc) on my local computer. We created a few "user-friendly" forms e.g. "Add new computer", "Add new department", "Add Location" etc. My manager wants to have an access to this database via webpage (our company's site on Sharepoint). I have a huuuuuge problem with it. I read that MS Access isn't support anymore by Microsoft so they don't recommend publishing on Sharpoint Access aplications. My question is what can i do with this problem. I can make everything once again using different tools, but i have no idea how to start. I need database where i will have list of computers, i need also some GUI for users (with menu, for simple and "user-friendly" adding new computers, departmets etc.) and i need to have it on Sharepoint. Could you help me? I'm a begginer developer and i have nobody who could help me with the concept of this small project. I have no idea about sharepoint and unfortunatelly i even don't have any access to try do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Classic Access is a Windows app.  Microsoft began but then ended & deprecated their attempt to have an Access Web app.

One can get remote connectivity to a Windows app (Access) a couple of different ways:
 + VPN, GoToMyPC, remote connection
 + SharePoint - the same as sharing any file i.e. Word, Excel, etc.

These aren't a multi user deployment - just allowing a single user to get to their app from a remote location.

For a browser based database with a small set of users - you probably don't want to build one from scratch and instead use a commercial service out there: Knack, AirTable, Soho.